# Simple and lossless video-only codec supported by avconv

Tags: png, avconv, video-codecs

This question is half StackOverflow and half SuperUser

I need information about simple and lossless video-only codecs that works in avconv. The purpose is to let screencap[1] produce one file for the entire sequence instead of one file per frame. The most straight-forward way is to write an MNG-VLC file instead of tons of PNG:s. However, no one seems to support that format, so I wonder if avconv does.

Requirements of the codec:

- Easy to implement
- Lossless
- Decoding supported by avconv
- Compression speed is a priority over file size
- RGB-24 should be a supported pixel format
- No inter-frame differencing (That makes multi-threading harder)
- Not covered by any weird patents

If the question is to broad, it is good to get some clues where to start. I do not request a tool or library but technical information on the complexity of say ffv1.

[1] https://github.com/milasudril/screencap

Comment: The half that is StackOverflow is requesting for a tool or library (etc.).

Comment: @Jongware Or rather, the so part is technical insight in different codecs. The tool part "how do I convert from format X to fromat Y" is su.